# Remove parentheses and doubles quotes from string after JSON stringfy

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I want to send data to the API,so I am passing array to the ajax request.First i did the `JSON.stringfy()`.

```
var string = JSON.stringify(Allsubjects);
//string = "["Mathmatics","English","Hindi","Science","Social Science"]"
```

***Note : After stringify it adds extra double quotes before and after paranthises***

I want to the output like:

```
Mathmatics,English,Science
```

without any doube quotes, Paranthises and single quotes.

Data needed to be sent :

```
data: { classes_sections:"{'2':['E']}",
        subjects:"{'data':['Science','English','Maths','Others']}"
       },
```

API structure

```
 "E": { "subject": [   "Science",
                        "English",
                        "Maths",
                        "Others"
                    ]
       },
```

Comment: are you writing in JS

Comment: @Thunder Yes Bro:)

Comment: subjects:"{'data':[' "+string+" ']}"

Comment: check my answer below buddy

Comment: why you are  converting to JSON if you want to send as an traditional array? just send as array to ajax call with traditional flag set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `join` instead of `stringify`

```js
var Allsubjects = ["Mathmatics","English","Hindi","Science","Social Science"];
var string = Allsubjects.join(",");

console.log( string );
```

---

If you are passing a json string to your API, you can just:

```
var Allsubjects = ["Mathmatics", "English", "Hindi", "Science", "Social Science"];
var classes_sections = ["E"];
var class = "2";

data: {
    classes_sections:'{"' + class + '":' + JSON.stringify(classes_sections) + '}',
    subjects: '{"data":' + JSON.stringify(Allsubjects) + '}'
},
```

Or you can just structure the JSON

```
var Allsubjects = ["Mathmatics", "English", "Hindi", "Science", "Social Science"];
var classes_sections = ["E"];
var className = "2";

//Structure JSON
var subjectJSON = { data : Allsubjects };
var classJSON = {};
classJSON[ className ] = classes_sections;

data: {
    classes_sections: JSON.stringify( classJSON ),
    subjects: JSON.stringify( subjectJSON )
},
```

Doc: [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: it outputs : string = "Mathmatics,English,Hindi,Science,Social Science"

Comment: Hmm.. I believe that's what you intended. Right? @NitishJaiswal

Comment: If you want to wrap each element with a single qoute, please check my updated answer.

Comment: its including double quotes.

Comment: It is because it is a string.

Comment: what is the sollution?

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve now. Is the API require a string or an array?

Comment: json format. if i send data like subjects:"{'data':['maths','English']}"  its succesfull inserted. so i am pushing all the subjects to the array and later i am passing this array to the request.

Comment: I added a sample that you can use using `JSON.stringify` please check @NitishJaiswal

Comment: Great! Happy to help @NitishJaiswal

Comment: how to send below data classes_sections:"{'2':['A']}",      in the place of A single data with variable name will come. and in the place of A the array will come , so how to pass.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @ eddie i want to use the variable name in the place of  "2". so please how to do escape character

Comment: Like what name?

Comment: like var class="2";     classes_sections:'{"class"':'+JSON.stringify(sectionsArray)+'}',